# How to Customize Alpha-Indexer While FastScrolling

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, sectionindexer

I have a `ListView` with `AlphaIndexer` implementation using `SectionIndexer`. I was wondering that if there is anyway to customize the Aplha-Indexer box shown while fast scrolling i.e. changing its color, background, text font/color etc. Like :

[image]

**Edited**
OR, When this box is adjacent to `FastScroll Thumb. like:`

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `Theme` inside your application with reference to  `res/val/style` and it's variant `styles-v11` or `styles-v14`.Then you can surely achieve customize `fastscroll indexer`.

Append these attributes in your `styles-v11` or `styles-v14` inside your parent `Theme` attribute.

```
<style name="Theme.Zname" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
<item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundLeft">@drawable/_ics_fastscroll_label_left</item> 
<item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@drawable/_ics_fastscroll_label_right</item>
</style>
```

Here as it is using `ActionBarSherlock`, so styles `fastScrollPreviewBackgroundLeft` and `fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight` are appended in it works with  `API >11`.

Put these inside `drawable/_ics_fastscroll_label_left`

[image: _ics_fastscroll_label_left]

Comment: Why it can't be done in `style` rather than `style-v11`.

Comment: I included these lines in my `style-11` file as : 
  
  `<style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        

<item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundLeft">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
        

<item name="android:fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    

</style>`

But its just changing the color of rectangular box and the triangular shape is not showing.

Comment: @BSTKaal : As you are using `android:color` it will definitely shows rectangular box only. Try to use your `custom drawable` with triangular shape in it. As i have already stated in answer.

Comment: @BSTKaal : You can add `fastScrollPreviewBackgroundLeft` or `fastScrollPreviewBackgroundRight` inside your `styles` incase if you are using Theme.Holo. For more information went through these https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/themes.xml and  why i stated to use it in `styles-v11` as it's added in API 11 http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#fastScrollPreviewBackgroundLeft

Comment: Hello @Vikalp Patel, can u plz take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24863038/avoid-swiperefresh-while-fastscrolling-in-android plz, i m stuck in the middle of app